# To store a collection of values from a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

pseudo code:

```
If a=b then
result= a . cells(start,1).value
end if
```

If column have multiple matches, how can I store those many matching values in a variable? and how can I add that onto the input box, where the user can select from it, when it prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an array? (This code is completely untested)

```
Dim arrCount as Long
Dim temp() as Variant

arrCount = 1

If a = b then
    ReDim Preserve temp(1 to arrCount)
    temp(arrCount) = a.cells(start,1).value
    arrCount = arrCount + 1
End If
' Concatenate array together and separate by a semi-colon and a space for the delimiter character
InputBox.Value = Join(temp, "; ")
```

This might be a bit overkill depending on what you're actually trying to achieve however it will give you a lot more options then just storing the full result in a variable

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
If a=b then
    result= result & ";" & a.cells(start,1).value
end if
```

You could consider concatenating the result value (the example above shows how you could have a semi-colon delimited string of values that massed the a=b test)

You probably need to post your actual code though so it's possible to assist properly.